# Edit a Adobe Flash application exe file

Tags: xml, internationalization, adobe, flash

I have received a folder containing a Adobe Flash application as a exe file. When I double click on it, the program runs using the content in other folders (at the same location as the exe file). Those folders contain tons of XML files and swf files. 
Now this application needs to be internationalized, so we did this. We copied the whole folders along with the exe to another folder (say CONTENT_French) and another team translated the label content in the XML files to French. When I click on the exe file in the second folder (French), the file is not loading.

How do I debug this? How are these exe files (Adobe Flash application files) made and which IDE can I use to fix the issues?

Any pointers are appreciated !

Comment: I am afraid you will need the source code. These exe's are compiled with either Flash or Flash Builder - there is a way to create an exe out of an AIR project

Comment: @Philarmon thank you, will try to get the source code then (.fla files)